# use a matplotlib Figure in PyQt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

programming noob here. I'm trying to use a matplotlib widget in a PyQt4 GUI. The widget is similar to matplotlib's [example for qt](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html).

At some point the user needs to click on the plot, which I thought something like ginput() would handle. However, this doesn't work because the figure doesn't have a manager (see below). Note that this is very similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653092/using-matplotlib-axes-with-ginput-and-imshow) but it never got answered.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'manager'
Figure.show works only for figures managed by pyplot, normally created by pyplot.figure().
```

I'm assuming by "normally" there's a way around this.

Another simple script to demonstrate:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
# figure creation by plt (also given a manager, although not explicitly)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)
coords = plt.ginput() # click on the axes somewhere; this works
print(coords)

# figure creation w/o plt
manualfig = Figure()
manualaxes = manualfig.add_subplot(111)
manualaxes.plot(x,y)
manualfig.show() # will fail because of no manager, yet shown as a method
manualcoords = manualfig.ginput() # comment out above and this fails too
print(manualcoords)
```

As popular as pyplot is (I can't hardly find an answer without it), it doesn't seem to play nice when working with a GUI. I thought pyplot was simply a wrapper for the OO framework but I guess I'm just a noob.

My question then is this: 
Is there some way to attach pyplot to an instance of matplotlib.figure.Figure? 
Is there an easy way to attach a manager to a Figure? I found new_figure_manager() in matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg, but couldn't get it to work, even if it is the right solution.

Many thanks,

James

Comment: You wanna handle the button click event?

Comment: Specifically, yes; I worked around this with a canvas.connect() to the button press although it didn't help my understanding. Generally, I'd like my embedded matplotlib widget to have the methods pyplot has (gingput, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyplot` is just a wrapper for the OO interface, but it does a lot of work for you  read the example you link to again carefully, the

```
FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
```

line is very important as that is what tells the figure what canvas to use.  The `Figure` object is just a collection of `Axes` objects (and a few `Text` objects), the `canvas` object is what knows how to turn `Artist` objects (ie matplotlib's internal representation of lines, text, points, etc) in to pretty colors.  Also see [something I wrote](https://github.com/tacaswell/leidenfrost/blob/master/leidenfrost/gui/reader_gui.py#L481) for another embedding example which does not sub-class `FigureCanvas`.

There is a [PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2624) to make this process easier, but it is stalled while we get 1.4 out the door.

also see: [Which is the recommended way to plot: matplotlib or pylab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849483/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-plot-matplotlib-or-pylab/16849816#16849816), [How can I attach a pyplot function to a figure instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254379/how-can-i-attach-a-pyplot-function-to-a-figure-instance/14261698#14261698)

Comment: I understand about the FigureCanvas; that makes sense. I think I'm circling the solution, I just haven't gotten there =) I'll look at your work, thanks!